# KeyCloak custom REST Endpoint - Admin client classes not found

Tags: keycloak

I have implemented a custom REST endpoint in KeyCloak 9.0.3. This endpoint will be invoked by an external UI layer to complete the entire registration flow including creating the user and sending the verification flow.
In the SPI code, I am invoking the Admin REST client to create the user and send the verification email.
I get an error when I invoke this service.

`ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-42) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/admin/client/KeycloakBuilder`

My POM file has the dependency included -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas on what I am missing here? Or is there a problem with accessing the Admin REST API from within a custom SPI?

Comment: What's the scope of your dependency? is it getting into your final deployment (e.g. war/lib or  ear/lib)?

Comment: This is a jar.. it is using the default compile scope