# Keycloak admin client not found in custom event listener

Tags: maven, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm developing a custom event listener for keycloak and I need the admin client *(keycloak-admin-client)* to use some methods. I've added the dependency in the *pom* file, and I'm generating the jar with: `mvn clean install`

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <keycloak.version>20.0.2</keycloak.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The error I'm getting is:

`2023-01-27 17:33:47,009 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-4) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/admin/client/Keycloak`

Also tried with `<scope>provided</scope>`. I have reviewed this post: [KeyCloak custom REST Endpoint - Admin client classes not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270060/keycloak-custom-rest-endpoint-admin-client-classes-not-found) which is exposing the same issue.

Edited: tried [NoClassDefFoundError in a provider jar when using a class from org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.broker.util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778240/noclassdeffounderror-in-a-provider-jar-when-using-a-class-from-org-keycloak-auth) without success.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the admin client is not part of the Keycloak server. You have to add it to `/opt/keycloak/providers` in keycloak server, just like you do with your custom provider. I use `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy all dependencies into the `target/dependency` folder. Then I add those to `/opt/keycloak/providers` via Dockerfile:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

```
...
COPY ./dependency/*.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/
COPY *.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/
...
```

I intentionally do this in two steps because dependencies will change less often than the provider you write yourself, which makes building the Dockerfile more efficient.